# jquery ajax GET request comes back with undefined values

Tags: jquery, ajax, api

I'm following a tutorial for jQUery ajax and when I run a GET request my values come up undefined on my local host.

This is the HTML code

```
<div> 
<h1>jQuery Ajax</h1>
        <h2>Friends</h2>

        <ul id="friends">

        </ul>

        <h4>Add a Friend</h4>
        <p>name: <input type="text" id="name"></p>
        <p>drink: <input type="text" id="drink"></p>
        <button id="add-order" class="btn btn-primary">Add!</button>
</div> <!--end of container-->
```

Here's my jQuery code:

```
  var $friends = $('#friends');

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://rest.learncode.academy/api/johnbob/friends',
    success: function(){
        $.each(friends, function(i, friend){
            $friends.append('<li>name: '+friend.name+' , age: '+friend.age+' </li>');


        })

    }
});
```

Here's the link to the REST API that I'm trying to request information from:

```
http://rest.learncode.academy/
```

Comment: pass the data to the success function eg. "success: function(friends){..."

Answer (score 0):

add friends to success function callback

```
success: function(data){
        $.each(data, function(i, friend){
            $friends.append('<li>name: '+friend.name+' , age: '+friend.age+' </li>');
        })

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have variable in success function callback to hold the result from the GET call.

```
success: function(data){
    $.each(data, function(i, friend){
        $friends.append('<li>name: '+friend.name+' , age: '+friend.age+' </li>');
    })
}
```

See [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)